# How to call a new GUI or form inside a GUI or form in python?

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple chat server using socket programming in python. I'm using Tkinter to build the GUI. here's my problem, I have a login.py file which makes me see the form of login. then I have this signup.py . now I want to navigate to signup form from login form when I click the button signup. please help! here is my SAMPLE code. just for navigating.

**login.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
import Signup

class Login():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Welcome to Login")
        self.btnSignup = Button(self.root, text="Not a member? Sign up now!", relief=FLAT,
                                borderwidth=1, font=("Century Gothic",11,'normal'),
                                command = self.callSignup, fg="white",bg="#0866c6", 
                                activebackground="#404040",activeforeground="white")
        self.btnSignup.place(width = 250, height = 25, x = 10, y = 10)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def callSignup(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        self.obj = Signup.signup("james")
        self.obj.display()
```

**signup.py**

```
from Tkinter import *

class signup():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def display(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Welcome " + self.name)            
        self.root.mainloop()
```

when I run the code, I can open the form of signup. but self.root.destroy() on login,py does not work! please, help me! thanks.

Comment: Is your issue that the login window doesn't close when you click the signup button? If so then move the destroy line to call first then create signup object.

Comment: thank you bro! that solved my problem, I didn't think of that method because I think it will destroy the whole program and it will not enable to execute the code to call the obj to display the other form. thank you! :)

Comment: Your welcome. The problem was when you create an new Tk instance it causes an infinite loop (root.mainloop) so it never reaches the destroy line.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to resolve your problem using 2 methods.

So basically, you are looking for this:

- The user clicks on the sign up button:

  [image]
- The click must prompt a sign up window: [image]

## First method:

The first method suggests a redesign of your application: I mean,  for the purpose of this task (as it is), it could be better for you to gather the windows in the same module instead of two separate `login.py` and `signup.py` modules. I prefer to start with approach as it has a second advantage of clearing the solution to your problem simply. Let's call our module `loginsignup.py`.

Within the constructor of the of the class, set the Frame widget within the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
```

For better design, it is good to separate the GUI design in a separate function that we call, for example, `initialize_membership_interface()`. This method must be, of course, called in the body of the constructor above:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize_membership_interface()
```

`initialize_membership_interface()` instantiate 2 buttons and a label. Use the [`grid()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html) method to organize these 3 widgets within the frame:

```
def initialize_membership_interface(self):
        self.parent.title('Membership Area')
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.config(background = "lavender")    

        self.label_welcome = Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="Not a member? Please sign up: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_welcome.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)

        self.button_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent,font="Helvetica 10 bold", text = "Sign up", command = self.signup)
        self.button_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.button_cancel_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text = "Cancel",font="Helvetica 10 bold", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.button_cancel_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
```

We then program a second method called, for instance, `signup()` to draw the second GUI to display the subscription elements properly said.

**1. First trick:**

But your problem is how to bind `self.button_signup` to `signup()` method. You can solve this using the [`command`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method) modifier:

```
self.button_signup = Tkinter.Button(command = self.signup)
```

**2. Second trick:**

The solution to the second problem you are face consists in using the [`Toplevel()`](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html) method to display the second (largest) window above as a child to the first (small) one:

```
def signup(self):
        self.signup_window = Tkinter.Toplevel(self)
        self.signup_window.wm_title("Sign up Area")
        self.signup_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.signup_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        # Member's first name
        self.label_firstname = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="First name: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_firstname.grid(row = 0, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_firstname = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_firstname.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        # Member's last name
        self.label_lastname = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Last name: ", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_lastname = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        # Member's email
        self.label_email = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Email: ", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_email.grid(row = 2, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_email = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        # Member's password
        self.label_password = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Password: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_password.grid(row = 3, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_password = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window, show = "*")
        self.entry_password.grid(row = 3, column = 1)        
        # Member's repeat password
        self.label_repeat_password = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Repeat password: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_repeat_password.grid(row = 4, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_repeat_password = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window, show = "*")
        self.entry_repeat_password.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        self.button_submit = Tkinter.Button(self.signup_window,text="Submit",font="Helvetica 10 bold")
        self.button_submit.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.button_cancel_submit = Tkinter.Button(self.signup_window,text = "Cancel",font="Helvetica 10 bold", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.button_cancel_submit.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
```

**3. Full application:**

Here is the full application coded in one single module:

```
'''
Created on Mar 6, 2016

@author: Bill Begueradj
'''

import Tkinter

class Begueradj(Tkinter.Frame):
    '''Define a GUI for membership subscription.    
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''Set the constructor.
        Set the parent Frame widget.
        Call initialize_membership_interface() to draw the GUI
        '''
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize_membership_interface()

    def initialize_membership_interface(self):
        ''' Draw a simplistic GUI consisting of 2 buttons.
        The user clicks on the sign up button to land on the second
        window dedicated for the subscription process.
        The user may click on the cancel button to leave 
        the application.
        '''
        self.parent.title('Membership Area')
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.config(background = "lavender")    

        self.label_welcome = Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="Not a member? Please sign up: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_welcome.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)

        self.button_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent,font="Helvetica 10 bold", text = "Sign up", command = self.signup)
        self.button_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.button_cancel_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text = "Cancel",font="Helvetica 10 bold", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.button_cancel_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)

    def signup(self):
        '''Design the subscription window.
        Bind this child window to the main one using Tkinter.Toplevel()
        '''
        self.signup_window = Tkinter.Toplevel(self)
        self.signup_window.wm_title("Sign up Area")
        self.signup_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.signup_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        # Member's first name
        self.label_firstname = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="First name: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_firstname.grid(row = 0, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_firstname = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_firstname.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        # Member's last name
        self.label_lastname = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Last name: ", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_lastname = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        # Member's email
        self.label_email = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Email: ", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_email.grid(row = 2, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_email = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        # Member's password
        self.label_password = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Password: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_password.grid(row = 3, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_password = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window, show = "*")
        self.entry_password.grid(row = 3, column = 1)        
        # Member's repeat password
        self.label_repeat_password = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Repeat password: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_repeat_password.grid(row = 4, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_repeat_password = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window, show = "*")
        self.entry_repeat_password.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        self.button_submit = Tkinter.Button(self.signup_window,text="Submit",font="Helvetica 10 bold")
        self.button_submit.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.button_cancel_submit = Tkinter.Button(self.signup_window,text = "Cancel",font="Helvetica 10 bold", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.button_cancel_submit.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)

def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    b = Begueradj(root)
    b.mainloop()
# Start of the main program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Second method:

The second method is split the previous method into two separate ones **login.py** and **signup.py** and thus respect your own design.

**1. signup.py:**

Here you keep the previous `signup()` method that we rename. for convenience, by `subscribe()` within the `signup.py` module but you need to pass a `Tkinter.Frame` widget    to the constructor of the unique class of this module in order to be able to use the [`Toplevel()`](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html) method:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
```

**2. login.py**

This module contains the previous `initialize_membership_interface()` method.

The main trick here is how to bind `subscribe()` method of *signup.py* and successfully pass the main `Tkinter.Frame` widget of *login.py* module to `button_signup` button. This is done this way:

```
self.button_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Sign up", command = signup.Signup(self.parent).subscribe)
```

**3. Full application:**

Here are the contents of the two modules:

- **signup.py**:

Of course, the main method (start of the program) does not concern this module:

```
'''
Created on Mar 6, 2016

@author: Bill BEGUERADJ
'''

import Tkinter

class Signup(Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # This will allow to pass the main Frame widget as an argument
        # to Signup class
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def subscribe(self):
        self.signup_window = Tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.signup_window.wm_title("Sign up Area")
        self.signup_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.signup_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        # Member's first name
        self.label_firstname = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="First name: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_firstname.grid(row = 0, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_firstname = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_firstname.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        # Member's last name
        self.label_lastname = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Last name: ", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_lastname = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_lastname.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        # Member's email
        self.label_email = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Email: ", anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_email.grid(row = 2, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_email = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window)
        self.entry_email.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        # Member's password
        self.label_password = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Password: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_password.grid(row = 3, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_password = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window, show = "*")
        self.entry_password.grid(row = 3, column = 1)        
        # Member's repeat password
        self.label_repeat_password = Tkinter.Label(self.signup_window,text="Repeat password: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_repeat_password.grid(row = 4, column = 0, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.entry_repeat_password = Tkinter.Entry(self.signup_window, show = "*")
        self.entry_repeat_password.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        self.button_submit = Tkinter.Button(self.signup_window,text="Submit",font="Helvetica 10 bold")
        self.button_submit.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.button_cancel_submit = Tkinter.Button(self.signup_window,text = "Cancel",font="Helvetica 10 bold", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.button_cancel_submit.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
```

- **login.py**

The main method must be executed in this module:

```
'''
Created on Mar 6, 2016

@author: Bill BEGUERADJ
'''
import Tkinter
import signup

class Begueradj(Tkinter.Frame):
    '''Define a GUI for membership subscription.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''Set the constructor.
        Set the parent Frame widget.
        Call initialize_membership_interface() to draw the GUI
        '''
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize_membership_interface()

    def initialize_membership_interface(self):
        ''' Draw a simplistic GUI consisting of 2 buttons.
        The user clicks on the sign up button to land on the second
        window dedicated for the subscription process.
        The user may click on the cancel button to leave 
        the application.
        '''
        self.parent.title('Membership Area')
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.parent.config(background = "lavender")    

        self.label_welcome = Tkinter.Label(self.parent,text="Not a member? Please sign up: ",anchor=Tkinter.W,background="dark slate gray",foreground="white", font="Helvetica 8  bold")
        self.label_welcome.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2, stick = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)

        self.button_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent,font="Helvetica 10 bold", text = "Sign up", command = signup.Signup(self.parent).subscribe)
        self.button_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
        self.button_cancel_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent,text = "Cancel",font="Helvetica 10 bold", command = self.parent.quit)
        self.button_cancel_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)


def main():
    ''' Define the main method.
    '''
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    b = Begueradj(root)
    b.mainloop()

# Start of the main application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that running both versions of solution I described here produces rather this GUI:

[image]

If you want to get the same visual effect for the buttons as in the screenshots above, you will need to use this [sign up](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/t/M/w/v/T/5/signup-md.png) and that [cancel](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/N/b/w/h/1/P/cancel-button-md.png) images.

To be able to load these pictures into their respective buttons, you need first to import:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Then you need to set the images as a background to the the two buttons:

```
# Setting images to the buttons
self.img_signup = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("img.png").resize((100,40),Image.ANTIALIAS))
self.img_cancel = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("cancel.png").resize((100,40), Image.ANTIALIAS))
self.button_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, image = self.img_signup,command = self.signup)
self.button_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
self.button_cancel_signup = Tkinter.Button(self.parent, image = self.img_cancel, command = self.parent.quit)
self.button_cancel_signup.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = Tkinter.E + Tkinter.W)
```

Comment: what a great answer! yes I finally solved it using what Steven Summers suggest, but I encountered a problem in login.py and signup.py so what I use is I combined them it  solved my problem. thank you for your great explanation! :)